# google api (403) Forbidden and said "User rate limit exceeded"

Tags: google-api, quota, google-developers-console, google-slides-api

I am receiving this error when trying to generate a document in Google slide.

Can someone tell me what are the limits as I have only done a couple of tests?

And how can I have more quota?

Comment: It's thoroughly described in the official documentation. :-) https://developers.google.com/slides/limits

Answer (score 0):

In the [google developer console](https://console.developers.google.com) go to the google slides api then the quota tab

The page lists the different quotas Read requests, write requests and Expensive read requests.

[image]

if there is a pencil next to the quota you can increase it.